# Retrieve MySQL Database from xampp

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I am using a storage software for my ICs,Caps and Resistors called "Elela" (http://www.mmvisual.de/).
The software is based around a mysql database which I hosted local with xampp. My Computer crashed (blown Motherboard) so I had to re-install most of it.

My Problem : Is there any chance to restore the lost database (I know the exact name: elela  and Username/Password)? I was looking for a *.sql file which I could load into the new xampp installation but was not lucky.

Thanks in advance!

Luke

Comment: You *might* be able to retrieve the data, depending on the storage engine used for the tables. If I recall correctly, the files for MyISAM tables can be copied from one installation of MySQL to another without issue, but InnoDB tables take a little more work. Try googling "copy mysql database files" or something similar.

Comment: Use the backup. You *do* have a backup, don't you?